# Weird serialisation behavior with HashMap

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Consider the three following classes:

- **EntityTransformer** contains a map associating an **Entity** with a String
- **Entity** is an object containing an ID (used by equals / hashcode), and which contains a reference to an **EntityTransformer** (note the circular dependency)
- **SomeWrapper** contains an **EntityTransformer**, and maintains a Map associating **Entity**'s identifiers and the corresponding **Entity** object.

The following code will create an EntityTransformer and a Wrapper, add two entities to the Wrapper, serialize it, deserialize it and test the presence of the two entitites:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception {

    EntityTransformer et = new EntityTransformer();
    Wrapper wr = new Wrapper(et);

    Entity a1 = wr.addEntity("a1");  // a1 and a2 are created internally by the Wrapper
    Entity a2 = wr.addEntity("a2");

    byte[] bs = object2Bytes(wr);
    wr = (SomeWrapper) bytes2Object(bs);

    System.out.println(wr.et.map);
    System.out.println(wr.et.map.containsKey(a1));
    System.out.println(wr.et.map.containsKey(a2));
}
```

The output is:

> {a1=whatever-a1, a2=whatever-a2}

> false

> true

So basically, the serialization failed somehow, as the map should contain both entities as Keys. I suspect the cyclic dependency between Entity and EntityTransformer, and indeed if I make static the EntityManager instance variable of Entity, it works.

**Question 1**: given that I'm stuck with this cyclic dependency, how could I overcome this issue ?

Another very weird thing: if I remove the Map maintaining an association between identifiers and Entities in the Wrapper, everything works fine... ??

**Question 2**: someone understand what's going on here ?

Bellow is a full functional code if you want to test it:

**Thanks in advance for your help :)**

```
public class SerializeTest {

public static class Entity
        implements Serializable
 {
    private EntityTransformer em;
    private String id;

    Entity(String id, EntityTransformer em) {
        this.id = id;
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Entity other = (Entity) obj;
        if ((this.id == null) ? (other.id != null) : !this.id.equals(
            other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 97 * hash + (this.id != null ? this.id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}

public static class EntityTransformer
    implements Serializable
{
    Map<Entity, String> map = new HashMap<Entity, String>();
}

public static class Wrapper
    implements Serializable
{
    EntityTransformer et;
    Map<String, Entity> eMap;

    public Wrapper(EntityTransformer b) {
        this.et = b;
        this.eMap = new HashMap<String, Entity>();
    }

    public Entity addEntity(String id) {
        Entity e = new Entity(id, et);
        et.map.put(e, "whatever-" + id);
        eMap.put(id, e);

        return e;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception {
    EntityTransformer et = new EntityTransformer();
    Wrapper wr = new Wrapper(et);

    Entity a1 = wr.addEntity("a1");  // a1 and a2 are created internally by the Wrapper
    Entity a2 = wr.addEntity("a2");

    byte[] bs = object2Bytes(wr);
    wr = (Wrapper) bytes2Object(bs);

    System.out.println(wr.et.map);
    System.out.println(wr.et.map.containsKey(a1));
    System.out.println(wr.et.map.containsKey(a2));
}



public static Object bytes2Object(byte[] bytes)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream oi = null;
    Object o = null;
    try {
        oi = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        o = oi.readObject();
    }
    catch (IOException io) {
        throw io;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cne) {
        throw cne;
    }
    finally {
        if (oi != null) {
            oi.close();
        }
    }

    return o;
}

public static byte[] object2Bytes(Object o)
    throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oo = null;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        oo = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

        oo.writeObject(o);
        bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {
        if (oo != null) {
            oo.close();
        }
    }

    return bytes;
}
}
```

**EDIT**

There is a good summary of what is potentially in play for this issue:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4957674

> The problem is that HashMap's readObject() implementation , in order
> to re-hash the map, invokes the hashCode() method of some of its keys,
> regardless of whether those keys have been fully deserialized.
>
> If a key contains (directly or indirectly) a circular reference to the
> map, the following order of execution is possible during
> deserialization --- if the key was written to the object stream before
> the hashmap:
>
> 1. Instantiate the key
> 2. Deserialize the key's attributes
>    2a.  Deserialize the HashMap (which was directly or indirectly pointed to by the key)
>    2a-1.   Instantiate the HashMap
>    2a-2.   Read keys and values
>    2a-3.   Invoke hashCode() on the keys to re-hash the map
>    2b.  Deserialize the key's remaining attributes
>
> Since 2a-3 is executed before 2b,  hashCode() may return the wrong
> answer, because the key's attributes have not yet been fully
> deserialized.

Now that does not explain fully why the issue can be fixed if the HashMap from Wrapper is removed, or move to the EntityTransformer class.

Comment: Why are you making your `equals` logic so convoluted? Why not just `return (this.id == null) ? (other.id == null ) : this.id.equals( other.id );` ?

Comment: The equals / hashcode were automatically generated by NetBeans for this example, and as this is not really the root of my problem, I didn't take the time to review it

Comment: @truheality because that violates the contract of equals!

Comment: @ecniv, circular references don't cause issues with serialisation. It's specifically designed to cope with that by keeping track of objects it's already serialised and replacing them with back-references if they're re-serialised. In fact, this can be a source of other bugs and/or memory issues.

Comment: So that's even more strange I guess ? The code is quite simple, and yet I can't figure out what's going on..

Comment: @dty How? Isn't this equivalent to the other way?

Comment: No. 1) it won't compile. You need to cast `obj` to get `other`. 2) if you skip the class checks you can get a `ClassCastException` when you should just return `false`. 3) if you pass it `null`, it will throw a `NullPointerException` when it should just return `false`. 4) it has the potential to be asymmetric (as does the OP's version, to be fair).

Comment: @dty I meant just replace the if statement and last return statement with that. I'm not a moron.

Comment: Well, you didn't say that, and I'm not a mind-reader. You said "why make your equals so convoluted, why not just ...", which sounds a lot like "replace it with this" to me.

Comment: @dty when someone says something and there is one way to interpret it as idiocy and another way to interpret it as a valid comment, I tend to give people the benefit of the doubt and interpret it the way that actually makes sense.

Comment: I agree, but if I had a dollar for every time somebody had written an equals() method that looks exactly like what you wrote, I'd be a VERY rich man. And I'm not even kidding. There are a large number of people out there who think what you wrote would be perfectly acceptable as the whole equals() method. Plus, as a software engineer, I prefer precise language over hoping people interpret my communications in a particular way.

Comment: It's probably a manifestation of [this reported bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4957674).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with circular initialisation. Whilst Java Serialisation can handle arbitrary cycles, the initialisation has to happen in some order.

There's a similar problem in AWT where `Component` (`Entity`) contains a reference to its parent `Container` (`EntityTransformer`). What AWT does is to make the parent reference in `Component` `transient`.

```
transient Container parent;
```

So now each `Component` can complete its initialisation before `Container.readObject` adds it  back in:

```
    for(Component comp : component) {
        comp.parent = this;
```

Comment: Hum that seems to be an interesting solution... Now what if I don't have any possibility to change the EntityTransformer (e.g. it is an external class from a commercial library) ?

Comment: I found that puting the map contained in the Wrapper,directly into the EntityTransformer seems to fix the issue. Very strange...

Comment: Serializing the reference to the EntityTransformer did the job and seems to be a cleaner solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Even stranger, if you do

```
Map<Entity, String> map = new HashMap<>(wr.et.map);
System.out.println(map.containsKey(a1));
System.out.println(map.containsKey(a2));
```

After serializing and de-serializing, you will get the correct output.

Also:

```
for( Entity a : wr.et.map.keySet() ){
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    System.out.println(wr.et.map.containsKey(a));
}
```

Gives:

```
a1
false
a2
true
```

I think you found a bug. Most likely, serialization broke the hashing somehow.
In fact, I think you might have found [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4957674).

Comment: The more I play with it, the more I tend to agree.

Answer (score 0):

Can you override the serialization to transform the reference into a key value before serializing, and then transform it back on deserialization?

It seems like it would be pretty trivial to find the hash key of the EntityTransformer when serializing and use that value instead, (maybe provide a value in the structure called parentKey) and null out the reference. Then when reserializing, you find the EntityTransformer associated with that key value and assign its reference.

Comment: Hum I'm not sure I understand well your suggestion. How should I find the EntityTransformer upon reserializing if it has not actually been serialised ? (note that in my use case, the serialization is usefull to pass objects to other programs which does not necessarily share the same VM).